# Sort array for object key that holds unique value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var coll = [
{
    prop1:true,
    prop2:false,
    id:"888399"
},
{
    prop1:true,
    prop2:true,
    id:"/XS-555224"
},
{
    prop1:false,
    prop2:false,
    id:"/DL-555444"
}
]
```

I want to sort the array so that the element with the ID that begins with "/DL" (for which there will always only be one) always starts at the top. How do I do that?

I don't feel like a custom sort will be the best choice because I don't have to compare elements against one another, I only have to find the one with the "/DL", slice it out, and insert it at the beginning of the array.

However, to do that, I'll still need to iterate over each element of the array to find the element and then perform a couple operations. So then I start thinking that I might as well just do the sort. The problem is how to write the correct condition to compare 2 items and checking the beginning of the ID string. So I figure that I can just simply test for the beginning of the String and return the value myself without comparison.

So I try this:

```
coll.sort(function(a,b){
    var itemA = a.id;
    var itemB = b.id;

    if(itemA.lastIndexOf("/DL") === 0){
        return 1;
    }
});
```

But this comparison isn't working. What is wrong with my custom compare function? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are just looking for one record to move to the front you still need to check both parameters in the sort, it could be either one.

```
coll.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.id.indexOf('/DL') === 0 ? -1 : b.id.indexOf('/DL') === 0 ? 1 : 0;   
});
```

Basically we want the '/DL' record to be the 'lowest' value in the array so it will show up first (sort orders things low to high).  If `a` is lower we return negative, if `b` is lower we return positive.  So when sorting if `a` is the /DL we need to return a negative.  If `b` is the /DL we return a positive.  So this expression in english is basically "Is `a` is our record? -1. If not, is `b` our record? 1.  If neither then 0."

Comment: I like this and it works but the expression is a bit hard for me to understand. I feel like the condition of a.id should return a 1 instead of a -1.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't dealt with multiple ternary evaluations before.

Comment: No problem! I added an explanation to my answer not sure how clear it is but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var orderedArr = coll.sort(function(val){
    return !val.id.toString().startsWith('/DL');
});
```

[EDIT]

Once that you have user with IE, you can add this to make your life easier in the future:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
   String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
       position = position || 0;
       return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
   };
}
```

so you'll be able to use startsWith now and whenever you want.

Comment: I like this but can't use startsWith because we still have users on IE11.

Comment: @fumeng maybe it can help you now.